# SQLite Python printing in rows?

Tags: python, sqlite

Afternoon, i am trying to retrieve seat numbers from a database using the following code

```
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats")
    while True:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break
        print row[0]
```

But when i do so, it prints out each individual record one per line like so :

```
A1
A2
B3 etc..
```

But i want each row to print out with the same letter if that makes sense such as :

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
```

But i cant seem to get it like that ? How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Pro tip: you can loop over a cursor with rows like you can over any sequence:  `for row in cur: print row[0]` will work fine and is a lot simpler than your `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.groupby()` tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

for letter, rows in groupby(cur, key=lambda r: r[0][0]):
    print ' '.join([r[0] for r in rows])
```

The `groupby()` function loops over each row in `cur`, take the first letter of the first column, and give you a tuples with each `(letter, rows)` values. The `rows` value is another iterable, you can loop over that (with a `for` loop, for example) to list all rows that have that first letter.

This does rely on the rows being sorted already. If your rows alternate between first letters:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
A3
A4
```

it'll print those as separate groups:

```
A1 A2
B1 B2
A3 A4
```

You may want to add a `ORDER BY firstcolumnname` ordering instruction to your query to ensure correct grouping.

This is what I see when I create a test db:

```
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats ORDER BY code")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10b1a8730>
>>> for letter, rows in groupby(cur, key=lambda r: r[0][0]):
...     print ' '.join([r[0] for r in rows])
... 
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
```

Comment: Thank you so  much man, that make sense. But one problem, the first row which is A1 Doesnt display?

Comment: @CharlieSay: Did you do anything else with `cur` before passing it to `groupby`? If you called `fetchone()` on it already then that first row will have been consumed already, `groupby` does not 'rewind' the query.

Comment: if choice == "F":
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Day = 'F'")
        while True:
            if row == None:
                 break
            for letter, rows in groupby(cur, key=lambda r: r[0][0]):
                 print ' '.join([r[0] for r in rows])

Comment: @CharlieSay: No, loose the `while True` altogether. You do *not* need it. See the example I posted at the end of my answer; I go from `execute()` straight to the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help Martijn - Would ask of one more question , on each end of the row as in A1 / A18 Or whatever the seats would be - they are disabled seats and it is indicated in the database with a field called 'Disabled' = Y/N how would i get them to display in a line? if you get what i mean?

Comment: Extend the `key` function to add the field: `key=lambda r: (r[0][0], r[1])` where I assume that `r[1]` is the `Disabled` column. Adjust your `ORDER BY` as needed. Now `groupby()` will create a new group of rows when the `disabled` value changes.